# Looking for a char in a char array gives segmentation fault

Tags: c

I have a char array inside a struct.

```
myStruct->string;
```

I can actually print the `myStruct->string` and everything is there, the memory is also allocated correctly.

The problem is when I try to find `'\n'` I am trying to count how many new lines. Here is the code:

```
while(myStruct->string)
{
    if(strchr('\n', myStruct->string))
        myStruct->numbLines++;

    myStruct->string++;

}
```

I think the if statement is the problem.

Comment: Nothing changes `data` in the while loop, when do you expect that `while` to actually finish?

Comment: note that `myStruct->string++;` changes the pointer within the struct permanently

Comment: data was a typo. Thanks for telling me that myStruct->string++ changes the pointer permanently because then this code above is going to break everything.

Comment: If `myStruct->string++` compiles, then `string` must be a pointer, not an array, so you *don't* have "a char array inside a struct".

Comment: can you show: 1) the definition of your struct 2)how/where you allocate the memory for the string 3)how you set myStruct->string ... its just guess-work without those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of strchr() here does not really make sense to me. I would suggest the following:

```
char* ptr = mystruct->string;//make a copy of the pointer so that the original is not changed
while(ptr)
{
    if( (*ptr) == '\n' )
        myStruct-->numbLines++;
    ptr++;    
}
```